# Установка новой OC и удаление старой

Tags: linux, windows, установка, windows-xp, altlinux

Как установить OC AltLinux LXDesktop 6.0 версия lite если на компьютере стоит windows xp ?

Comment: А откуда такое желание ставить именно альт? В школе требуют?

Comment: Ставьте в виртуалку под XP.

Comment: да просто xp надоела хочется новую

Comment: Тогда форматируйте диск и ставьте.

Comment: @skegg это был весьма удачный лёгкий выпуск, между прочим; ну а сейчас я бы посоветовал http://altlinux.org/starterkits

Answer (score 2):

Так же как и любую другую операционку..
есть 2.5 варианта:
1 - полный формат харда, разметка разделов, установка новой операционки
2 - если хадр поделен на разделы: ставим новую операционку на другой раздел.
2.5 - если хард не разделен: отрезаем кусок харда под новую операционку и ставим. ( есть большие шансы похерить старую )

P.S: любая OS при установке в полной мере подсказывает юзеру...
P.P.S: чтобы запустить инсталляцию обычно надо запихать балванку с сидюк, и на экране загрузки системы (там где обычно написано имя вашей материнки ) нажать F8 потом выбрать ваш CD/DVD привод в роли загрузчика.. ( зависит от настроек в BIOS - primary boot loader)